# How to define a machine state

Tags: powershell, powercli

Hi im trying to use powershell to define if a machine in vmware is in Template state or VM state and according to the state do some actions.

im having trouble with defining...

Tried several ways and got to the example below.

this is what i got until now:

```
$vm = "Test"

$vms = Get-VM -Name $vm -ErrorAction SIlentlyContinue
$templates = Get-Template -Name $vm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


if ($templates.HostId.StartsWith("HostId")) {

Echo $templates
}

else {

echo $vms

}
```

Im getting an error when not in template name as it cant find the "HostId" object... which is kinda obvious. any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean Template state or VM state? if it's a VM, it's a VM object, and if it's template it's template

Comment: I want to write a script that a part of it need to find out if the template is in a vm state and if it is to roll it back to a template state.

Comment: The variable $templates will be 'false' in an if statement since it holds no value if there is no template for Test. Therefor if ($templates) { <ActionIfTrue> } should work in your current script.

Comment: That simple?! thanks Jonas ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$template= Get-view -viewtype VirtualMachine -property config, name| where {$_.config.template -eq $true}
```

Set flag to false to find just VMs.